# SpriteKit SKNode does not collide with edge

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm making a game in SpriteKit with Swift. I cannot for the life of me figure out why my node does not collide and bounce off the screen, as is default behavior for an SKSpriteNode.

Here's all my code from three different files:

GameViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    let battleScene = CSLevel()
    battleScene.size = view.frame.size
    battleScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(battleScene)
}
```

CSLevel:

```
//sorry here's the real code     
class CSLevel: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var myWorld: SKNode!
    var leader: CSCharacter?

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        setUpScene()
        setUpCharacters()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)


    }

    func setUpScene() {
        //Take care of setting up the world and bring in property list

        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) //0,0 to 1,1

        myWorld = SKNode()
        self.addChild(myWorld)

        let map = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "map")
        map.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        myWorld.addChild(map)

        myWorld.xScale = 1
        myWorld.yScale = 1

        //Setup physics
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -1)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        myWorld.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: screenFrame)
        myWorld.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    }

    func setUpCharacters() {
        leader = CSCharacter()
        myWorld.addChild(leader!)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == wallCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == wallCategory {

        }
    }
}
```

CSCharacter:

```
class CSCharacter: SKNode {

    var character: SKSpriteNode! //this will be the actual image you see of the character

    override init() {
        super.init()

        character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "character")
        self.addChild(character)

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: character.frame.size.width / 2)
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 5
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true

        self.xScale = 2
        self.yScale = 2

        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Is this a bug or something? Running Xcode beta 7.1. I'm literally following a tutorial and it doesn't behave the same way the guy's does, even as I type function for function what he's typing. Any help or clarifications appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Here# (hope this helps)

Try adding "skView.showsPhysics = true" right below "skview.showsNodeCount = true"
This will automatically trace lines around your physicsbodys.
When you run your app you should see a thin blue line around your skscene where your edge loop is.
If not you may need to add a argument to "let battleScene = CSLevel()".
So that "let battleScene = CSLevel()" is now "let battleScene = CSLevel(size: skView.frame.size)".

In other words, your node may be falling through the edge loop because the size of the edge loop is not specified